# Schedulers.immediate() not working with command line gradle tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java

I'm trying to test a presenter that use RxJava to retrieve data from an interactor. In the setup method I'm doing something like:

```
@Before 
public void setup() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });
}
```

So in my test method I can test the presenter call:

```
@Test
public void testLoad() {
    presenter.load();
    verify(view).dataLoaded(data);
    verify(interactor).load();
}
```

If I run the test with Android Studio everything work as expected, the issue is that If I try on command line

```
gradle test
```

Then the test fails because:
`Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

So I've tried to put a Thread.sleep(2000) right after the call to the presenter and then it works, so I guess the Schedulers.immediate(); is not working from command line but I have no idea why and how to debug/fix. Do you have any idea?

EDIT: presenter implementation ->

```
public void load() {
    Observable<List<Data>> obs = interactor.load()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    obs.subscribe(new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Data> data) {
            view.dataLoaded(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you add some logs in `getMainThreadScheduler` to check if it's called? You may have other race conditions in your codes. It would be great to show how you use schedulers in your codes.

Comment: Your `load` implementation is asynchronous (subscribed in Schedulers.io()). Hence you should not verify after `load` is called at once.

Comment: yes you are right, I've actually solved removing all the dependecy of rxjava in the presenter, so there is a wrapper that calls rxjava but in the test I'm using a different wrapper that doesn't use rxjava. At the end, I don't want to test rxjava but the logic of my presenter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can mock RxJava Schedulers as well.

```
RxJavaHooks.reset();
RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(scheduler -> Schedulers.immediate());
```

Typically a good thing to call reset on setup & teardown.